# Find Gaps between months

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a date field, a person's name and a unique identifier. The dates are all within 2015 and are by week-end date. For example 2015-12-05 , then 2015-12-12. I need to find a list of the unique identifiers that have a gap of at least 3 months of data.

So if unique identifier A, has entries of 2015-12-12 and 2015-07-25, then I would want to see it in my results. If its entries are more consistent, say one week per month then I do not want to see it in my results. I need to show all unique identifiers with a 3 month gap anywhere in 2015.

I'm not really sure where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: WHERE NOT EXISTS() would be a good idea.

Comment: Is the unique identifier per-row or per-person? Please post the table structure (`CREATE` statement for the table will suffice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Rank function and Ranked the months that existed for each identifier on the table. For example,

```
select identifier,month,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY month ) rnk
```

[image: table1]

I then uploaded all the data from this query into a temp table. Then I used the lead and lag functions to pull the previous rows month and the next rows month. 
Be sure you have all data ordered properly. I inserted that into a temp table too.

```
select identifier,rnk,lag(month) over (order by identifier) PreviousMonth,month,lead(month) over (order by identifier) NextMonth from #table group by identifier,month,rnk
```

Then I queried that temp table to show where a gap was 3 months or greater.

```
select identifier, PreviousMonth,NextMonth,Month-PreviousMonth as Month_Gap from #table2 where month-PreviousMonth >0 and month-PreviousMonth >=3 and rnk>1
```

I hope this helps and makes sense. 
So my final output ended up being something like the following.

[image: table2]

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this :

**ANSI 89**

```
SELECT t1.* from
your_table as t1,your_table as t2
where DATEDIFF(month,t1.your_date_field,t2.your_date_field) >= 3 and 
t1.your_unique_id=t2.your_unique_id and 
not exists(
    select 1 
    from your_table as t3 
    where t3.your_unique_id = t1.your_unique_id and
    DATEDIFF(month,t1.your_date_field,t3.your_date_field) < 3 
)
```

**ANSI 92**

```
SELECT t1.* from
your_table as t1 
    inner join your_table as t2 on t1.your_unique_id=t2.your_unique_id
where DATEDIFF(month,t1.your_date_field,t2.your_date_field) >= 3 and 
not exists(
    select 1 
    from your_table as t3 
    where t3.your_unique_id = t1.your_unique_id and
    DATEDIFF(month,t1.your_date_field,t3.your_date_field) < 3 
)
```

You need more explanation ?

Comment: Is t1 and t2 a join on the same table?

Comment: This doesn't really work. If there was an entry every month for 6 months this would still return some results. It is also using the old ANSI-89 style joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use APPLY like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id FROM <table> t1 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 t.date FROM <table> t 
        WHERE t.id = t1.id AND t.date < t1.date ORDER BY t.date DESC) t2
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, t1.date, t2.date) >= 3
```